# How to prevent right to left alignment for arabic language?

Tags: android

```
<activity
            android:name=".activity.LoginAct"
            android:supportsRtl="false"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
```

I have added the `supportsRtl` property to false so that it is always left aligned but somehow it is not working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace -- android:supportsRtl="false"

With -- android:supportsRtl="false"
        tools:replace="android:supportsRtl"

This works for me.

Comment: this works perfectly